# How do I write Jasmine unit tests for an AngularJS application that will eventually be upgraded to Angular 6?

Tags: angularjs, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I have an AngularJS application that is going to be upgraded to Angular 6 very soon. However, the current AngularJS application has **zero** unit tests. Since I am tasked with doing the upgrade, I want to make sure that I have equal functionality between the legacy app and the eventual Angular 6 version, and my plan to do that is to use unit tests to ensure this.

This comes with unique problems. For example, controllers are no longer a thing along with $scope and $rootScope in Angular 2+, but I need to write unit tests for the existing controllers since none currently exist. However, if I spend the time and write the unit tests for the controller, those tests will very shortly be obsolete and useless.

Is the best way to simply write the tests for the AngularJS application, and then write a *second version* of those same unit tests, but for the Angular 6 components? Or is there another way I do not know of?

The current AngularJS version used by the application is 1.3.x, and the plan is to upgrade to Angular 6/7. The latest version of Karma and Jasmine are also being used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have any unit tests in current project with AngularJS I would suggest you to firstly migrate and then write tests. For me it would be a waste of time to create something that I will toss away after update, let's write once just after.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but how would I ensure full feature parity between the AngularJS and Angular version without the tests? This is a fairly large application.

Comment: They are two different types of frameworks so you almost cant?... There is a few terms being reused in ng2+ from AngularJS therefore might be some misunderstanding about similarity. I would suggest you to read [this](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-from-angularjs-to-angular) handy part of the upgrade guide on what approach to take.

Comment: Angular introduces a `TestBed` for running component tests. There's no equivalent from AngularJs. Any tests you write would have to be completely rewritten in the upgrade. You may be able to write some view tests with protractor, but anything you write will require substantial refactoring.